# Find unmatched variables in R

Tags: r

I merged two datasets but found that a handfull of records have differently coded results for a certain disease status. e.g

```
> ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
> status1 <- c(1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1)
> status2 <- c(1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1)
> df <- data.frame(ID, status1, status2)
> df
  ID status1 status2
1  1       1       1
2  2       1       1
3  3       1       1
4  4       1       2
5  5       2       1
6  6       1       1
7  7       1       1
8  8       1       1
9  9       1       1
```

Rows 4 and 5 should have the same result for status1 and status2. I'm trying to generate a table of all the discordants that would look like this

```
  ID status1 status2
4  4       1       2
5  5       2       1
```

The closest I've gotten is with

```
> discordant <- ifelse(df$status1 != df$status2,c(df$ID, df$status1, df$status2), NA)
> discordant
[1] NA NA NA  4  5 NA NA NA NA
```

I'm not sure why it is only giving me ID and not status1 and status2 as well.

Comment: The simplest way is `df[df$status1 != df$status2,]`

Comment: That's a lot simpler than my solution below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply this?

```
df[df$status1 != df$status2,]

ID status1 status2
4  4       1       2
5  5       2       1
```

Answer (score -1):

Ah, figured it out by combining ifelse with subset

```
> discordant <- subset(df, ifelse(df$status1 != df$status2,TRUE, FALSE))
> discordant
  ID status1 status2
4  4       1       2
5  5       2       1
```

Comment: `df$status1 != df$status2` gives logical output.